# How to implement country domains based on geo IP address in ASP.net?

Tags: subdomain, url-rewriting, iis, users, geotargeting

I want to configure a domain such that when the user goes to my website, the system identifies the IP country of user and auto changes `www.mysite.com/index.aspx` to

- `www.unitedstate.mysite.com` (for US People)
- `www.france.mysite.com` (for French People)
- `www.japan.mysite.com` (for Japanese People)

I want to develop my website globally, changing the language and currency by identifying the country of user visiting the website based on the IP address.

Can I do it?  I'm using IIS on a private ASP.net Windows Server.